# How to set computed property a value if it's not bound to component's data

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a component that has a computed property which gets its value from the Vuex store, like following:

```
computed: {
  details () {
    return this.$store.getters.getDetails
  }
}
```

getDetails getter returns an object with several properties.
Now the problem is, how to update properties of 'details' object in the component where it is defined?
If it was through the UI, then it could be done via v-model. But it's needs to be done via component's methods. Like the following:

```
methods: {
  someMethod () {
    // here I need to update props of 'details' object, but how?
  }
}
```

Comment: Define an action that calls a mutation in Vuex and set them. The computed will be automatically updated. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Vuex, do it in the store.

Let's say your `details` object is like this:

```
details: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

Then add a mutation for modifying the `details` object in the state (I used `and` because I don't know whether you only want to modify a property of the `details` or actually want to assign a new object to it):

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    details: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
  },
  getters: {
    getDetails: (state, getters) => {
      return state.details;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_DETAILS (state, payload) {
      this.$set(state.details, payload.key, payload.val)
    },
    REPLACE_DETAILS (state, payload) {
      state.details = payload
    }
  }
});
```

Then in your component:

```
// ...
methods: {
  // ...
  updateDetails(key, val) {
    this.$store.commit('UPDATE_DETAILS', { key, val });
  },
  replaceDetails(obj) {
    this.$store.commit('UPDATE_DETAILS', obj);
  }
}
```

Update: What I said is basically a longer explanation of what @Bert was trying to say in his comment.